# Image on Browse and upload file button

Tags: html

I want to have image button for "browse" and "upload"

I have textbox using the following code:

CSS

```
   .uploadpathdiv
    {
     margin:0;
     height:44px;
     width:464px;
     background:url('images/img-upload.png') no-repeat bottom;
    }


.uploadpath
{
 background:none;
 border:none;
 width:400px;
 height:40px;
 margin:0;
 padding: 2px 7px 0px 7px;
 font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="uploadpathdiv">
<input class="uploadpath" name="path" type="text" />
</div>
<img src="/themes/scaccarium/images/button-upload.png" />
<img src="/themes/scaccarium/images/button-browse.png" />
```

The image code is for both "browse" and "upload" button.

Please help me to correct the above code so that when i press the browse button i get "file selection option" as you see when you use `<input type = "file" name="browse">`. Secondly, the path of the file must be shown in the textbox above.

Thirdly when i press the upload button the file should be uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to target the "browse..." button of file upload controls via CSS.

A HTML-based workaround can be found here: [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) 
not sure whether it can do exactly what you need, but I think that's the closest you can get.

If you want full control over the control (no pun intended) you would have to use a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org). Note that those uploaders work a bit differently from a normal file upload control, so you may need to change your workflow to get it to work, and decide whether it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you so much it looks like what i want.

Answer (score 5):

If you label an image with the label tag, you can click on the image and it will select the browse button.

```
<div id="fileInput">
    <label for="FileID"><img src="ImageURL"></label>
    <input type="file" id="FileID"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the CSS properties we usually use to style form controls don’t have any effect on the upload control, there are ways to style it, a good example is [Here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html)

This technique basically sets the opacity of the control to 0 and placed another "styled" button underneath it. thus when clicking on the style button you are actually clicking the upload control.

I have spent many hours battling with custom file upload controls for clients and have found by far the best approach is making use of [Valums jquery file uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) everything is already built and you can customize as much as you want, also has drag and drop functionality.